# Create 3 UITextView Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I need to create 3 `UTextView` programmatically without the need to set each one to a variable using `for` loop.

Here is a demonstration:

```
for i in 1...3 {
    var textView = UITextView()
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

    textView.center = self.view.center
    textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.justified
    textView.textColor = UIColor.blue
    textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

    self.view.addSubview(textView)
}
```

How can I do this to make 3 text views and have the ability to control it?

Comment: You need to set the frame of the textView so it has a size.

Comment: What do you mean by *"have the ability to control it"*?

Comment: First thing is , you are creating textView at the same place (self.view.center) , Second , if you wanna control the textView you must have dedicated textview outlet for each .

Comment: brimstone I know that thanks.

Comment: rmaddy have the ability to set and get the text

Comment: Roy I know about the center, i will change it

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access the generated text views from other methods in your class or even after the posted `for` loop, then you need to keep references to them.

Create an array to hold each one. Then you can access then later using the array. If you only need this in the method that creates them then create the array as another local variable. If you need to access the text view's from other places in your class, then make the array a proper of your class (view controller).

```
var textViews = [UITextView]()
```

And then in your loop, add:

```
textViews.append(textView)
```

Later, when you need to access the text views you can iterate through the array or access individual elements as needed.

Comment: Thank you, that what is was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Just like @rmaddy said, you will need to store these textViews in an array.  You will also need to add constraints to the textViews to help them play nice with autolayout

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    var textViews = [UITextView]()

    func createUI() -> Void {
        for i in 1...3 {
            var textView = UITextView()
            self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

            textView.center = self.view.center
            textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.justified
            textView.textColor = UIColor.blue
            textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

            self.view.addSubview(textView)

            var vertContraint : NSLayoutConstraint
            if (i == 1) {
                vertContraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.topLayoutGuide, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
            } else {
                vertContraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: textViews[i - 1], attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8.0)
            }
            //Do the same for your leading, trailing edges
            textView.addConstraints([/*vertContraint, leadingContr, trailingContr*/])
            textViews.append(textView)   
        }             
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be assigning a tag to each one of the `UITextView` and then accessing it by assigned tag respectively.

Here is a demonstration of assigning tags:

```
for i in 1...5 {
    var textView = UITextView()
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

    textView.center = self.view.center
    textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.justified
    textView.textColor = UIColor.blue
    textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    textView.tag = i
    self.view.addSubview(textView)
}
```

And you can access any assigned `UITextView()` by tag:

```
self.view.viewWithTag(1)
self.view.viewWithTag(2)
...
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you thats what I wass looking for.